# extract kernel config (/proc/config.gz) from linux image file

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I have kernel configuration file available via /proc:

```
IKCONFIG_PROC=y
```

and I can show the config of the running kernel as:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz
```

However, how do I cat the config of a `vmlinuz` image that is not running?
I have `vmlinuz` image stored on the disk. How do I extract the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory the [`extract-ikconfig` script](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-ikconfig) from the kernel source can extract the embedded configuration from a kernel built with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y`. I don't have access to a kernel built this way so I can't test it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654291/how-to-extract-the-config-from-a-kernel-image-file-when-config-ikconfig-is-set-a) on Stack Overflow for what to do if your kernel was built with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m`.